# Build a 2D list of attributes from user input

Tags: python, list, input

I am interested in learning how to build a 2D list, where each row contains an object number in column one and its attributes in the following columns. This will be done for as many objects as the user defines. It would look like this:

```
Object1 big heavy square

Object2 small heavy round

Object3 small light round
```

So if the user says there are eight objects, a loop would ask for the object number, size, weight, and shape of each object and populate the list.

Comment: Instead of a list of lists, I'd suggest using a list of [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) (provided that those entries can be immutable)

Comment: Thanks for the response Tobias. I’m not really across tuples, but I will do some research on your suggestion and see what I can figure out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You've already done most of the work in your last paragraph. There are a few ways of doing this:

### Naïve `for` loop:

```
objects = []
for index in range(1, 9):
    size = input("Size: ")
    weight = input("Weight: ")
    shape = input("Shape: ")
    objects.append(["Object" + str(index), size, weight, shape])
```

### Nested `for` loop:

```
names = ["Size", "Weight", "Shape"]
objects = []
for index in range(1, 9):
    object = ["Object" + str(index)]
    for name in names:
        object.append(input(name + ": "))
```

### Nested list comprehension

```
names = ["Size", "Weight", "Shape"]
objects = [
    ["Object" + str(index)] + [
        input(name + ": ")
        for name in names
    ] for index in range(1, 9)
]
```

You can see that each version is based on the last. A list comprehension is a neat way of building a list; you may or may not have come across it before.

Comment: Cheers wizzwizz4, I’ll have a good crack at your suggestions. Lists are very new to me so I really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @Rodney I recommend working through [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/); it's really helpful. I didn't use it because it initially seemed too hard, but I find myself occasionally using it as a reference for some of the trickier parts of the language even now.